# Bar chart With Minus Value in IOS with both Orientation

Tags: objective-c, bar-chart

I am Using [this](https://github.com/Zomato/DR-charts) library to show bar chart with tooltip Now I want to Display value in Minus also means when minus value then bar should be display in down side. so how can I display Barchart with Minus value .

Answer (score 2):

The Library which you are using does not support for minus values. The only way would be to fork the library and modify it to suit your needs. I've used the code from [this library](https://github.com/Maheshme/MMGraphs) before for positive and minus values.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.

Comment: @riddhi Hope that helps. You may accept the answer if it works for you.